# Where can I get an introduction to the Colored HOMFLY Polynomial?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, knot-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

Where can I get an free introduction to the Colored HOMFLY Polynomial? It would be great If I could get an exposition of the invariant with regards to rational links, but I'm not holding my breath. I looked on google but could only find research level papers.

If I can't get a free introduction, what book do I need to purchase?

Comment: Could you say a little about your background and your motivation for learning about it?  (I'm not aware of any books about it, but I might be able to help you find some sort of reference that's useful for your purposes.)  You might also tag this topological-quantum-field-theory since the polynomial has to do with $U_q(sl(N))$ invariants.

Comment: My advisor studies Cluster Algebras, and in one of his papers he figured out how to recover the Jones polynomial of rational links from certain cluster variables. Others built on his work, doing the same for both the Alexander Polynomial and HOMFLY polynomial; he thought it would be a good summer project for me to extend his results to the colored HOMFLY polynomial. 

So really, I just need the most basic introduction possible, haha.

Comment: @KyleMiller what is the name of $U_q(sl(N))$? Is it the irreducible representation of $sl$ associated with the integer $q$?

Comment: It's the "quantum deformation" of the lie algebra $sl(N)$.  This is a Hopf algebra known as a "quantum group."  The $N=2$ case corresponds to the colored Jones polynomials. The $q=1$ case corresponds to the universal enveloping algebra of $sl(N)$ (and gives no interesting knot invariants).